# AWS Cognito for multiple/n number of domain

Tags: amazon-cognito

I am using AWS Cognito for user management (Sign/Sign-in). I have an arrangement where I am providing sub-domains to all users, for example (user1.example.com, user2.example.com, ....)

In the AWS Cognito console, I have to provide a redirect_uri now the problem is I have I cant change redirect_url for separate sub-domains. It will only redirect it to the domain which is specified in the console.

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple `redirect_uri`s in AWS Cognito console separating them by comma.
Cognito will only allow the registered `redirect_uri`s in the console, so you must register them to this console.
And then you can redirect in the web based on the sub-domain

Comment: i will be creating/add domain, this happens dynamically

Comment: Currently, Cognito doesn't support any SDK to register redirect_uri dynamically which means that it's impossible to do so.